# Boundaries of a cycloid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Supposing the Catenoid is parametrized by $x(u,v)=(acosh(u)cos(v),acosh(u)sin(v),au)$,where $u$ is a real number and $0<=R<2\pi$ and $a>0$ is fixed.

Given the pair of parallel circles $x^2+y^2=R^2, |z|=1$, for what values of $R$ is there at least one catanoid with the circles as boundary. (Hint: Graph $f(t)=tcosh(1/t))$

so i followed the hint and after a lot of fooling around with mathematica I have an inkling that the $R$ value is the local minimum value of about 1.5008.  but I have no idea how to prove that if it is indeed right.  any suggestions?

the next part of the problem asks for the values of R we found in the previous part of the problem, when we compare the area of the catenoids with $2\pi R^2$,  what value of R does the pair of disks have the least area?